# Solving the heat equation with boundary condition and zero initial condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I'm having trouble trying to solve this PDE:

\begin{aligned}
&u_{t}-k^{2} u_{x x}=0 ; \quad 0<x<l, \quad 0<t, \quad(0<k), \\
&u(0, t)=\cos (t) ; \quad 0 \leq t, \\
&u(l, t)=\sin (t) ; \quad 0 \leq t, \\
&u(x, 0)=0 ; \quad 0<x<l .
\end{aligned}

This is my line of reasoning so far: write $u= v + W$, where $W(x,t)= \frac{\sin(t)-\cos(t)}{l}x + \cos(t)$. With this, I reach a new problem that I have to solve:

\begin{aligned}
&v_{t}-k^{2} v_{x x}=-W_t ; \quad 0<x<l, \quad 0<t, \quad(0<k), \\
&v(0, t)= 0 ; \quad 0 \leq t, \\
&v(l, t)=0 ; \quad 0 \leq t, \\
&v(x, 0)=-W(x,0) ; \quad 0<x<l .
\end{aligned}

My problem is that now I have a nonhomogeneous PDE. How would I go on to solve this?

Comment: Separation of variables still works. See, e.g., [here](http://wwwarchive.math.psu.edu/wysocki/M412/Notes412_10.pdf).